# How to create an event on others google calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, google-calendar-api

I need to create an event on other person Google calendar (other person calendar declared as **public**) using jquery / JavaScript through **my login credential** (API key) or common credential (common API key).

I am able to create an event on my google calendar with my login credential using javascript. But iam struggling to add event on other calendar. Whether it is possible or not. I am new to this environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to add events to people's calendars.

1. Have the other person grant permissions to your app to create events on their calendar (that means getting their Oauth token)
2. Invite this other person as an attendee to your event.
3. Have the person share the calendar with you with write permissions (but this works poorly if the person is inside a domain that has restricted permissions to calendars).

Answer (score 0):

If a calendar is just made public, you will only be able to read the events on it. In order to create new events on that calendar, the calendar needs to be shared with you with the permissions to "Make changes to events". In the UI, this can be done by going to that calendar's settings and going to the "Share this Calendar" tab and explicitly adding the email address of the user that should be able to add events.

Comment: I need to perform the same thing via java script / jquery... Share any link to resolve my problem.